# Add Spatial Database Connection fails?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I created a Database Server (SQL Express 2008.)

I created a "New GeoDatabase..."

I double-click on "Add Spatial Database Connection."

I fill out the dialog and change the transactional version.

I press the "Test Connection" button. The "Test Connection" message box says, "Connection succeeded."

I press the "OK" button twice and... NO connection is created.

I cannot create a new spatial database connection.

(I searched for this on the ESRI forum and, of course, the question is there but as usual there is no answer.)

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Spatial Database Connection**

depends on the Version you are using:
(ArcGIS 9.3.1 and ArcGIS 10 are slightly different.)

"If you leave the Save the transactional version name with the connection file box checked, the user will always connect to the specified transactional version using this connection file. If unchecked, the user will be prompted to choose a version to connect to every time he or she reconnects using this connection file. Note that if you have chosen a historical version to connect to, this check box will be labeled Save the historical details with the connection file. If left checked, the user will always connect to the specified historical marker or date and time when using this connection file"

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_spatial_database_connections

Slightly different for ArcGIS 10
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002q00000081000000

Comment: It is version 10. The point of my post is that I do not get the name box that is referenced in steps 13. and 14. of the version 10 instructions you referenced. 13.Type a new name for the spatial database connection. 14.Press ENTER. When I press OK it just goes right back to ArcCatalog and the 2 adds are staring me in the face (grinning, I suspect) but NO connection has been created.

Comment: unfortunate for you is working here - are you on the latest service pack? [10-12-2011] http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1807

Comment: On Service Pack 2 now.  Will try 3.