# Cannot create new spatial database connection in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arccatalog

I have searched a lot in the net, but i just found [Add Spatial Database Connection fails?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18060/add-spatial-database-connection-fails) here.

However, I cannot see the confirmed answer.

I want to know if anyone has found the solution?
my ArcGIS desktop version and ArcSDE version is 10.0 and Sqlserver R2 2008.
The problem is that when i click test in spatial database connection wizard in ArcCatalog tree can see the message  "process succeed" but in fact after clicking ok nothing is created.

Comment: Try downloading the latest service pack

Comment: you mean download service pack of both ArcGIS Desktop and ArcSDE?

Comment: I use windows 7_ 64 bit. Do you think it may cause such problem?

Comment: @GISKid i downloaded both ArcGIS Desktop and ArcdSDE latest service packs. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i can do it by create arcsde connection tools in work space in  data management tools by using arc toolbox. it works. i do believe that toolboxes works properly when some short cut solution doesn't work. now i can see all feature tables in management studio.